# Get-Help throwing ParserError

Tags: powershell

If I run `get-help get-member`, then everything is output as expected (I have not gotten any errors running `get-help` for a non-wildcard search).

However, executing `get-help get-*` (as per [this example](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb648604%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) it outputs 93 commands (the last one being `Get-TroubleshootingPack`), and then (after hanging for ~10 seconds) it throws the following error:

```
get-help : Unrecoverable error in Windows PowerShell.
At line:1 char:1
+ get-help get-*
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-Help], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Parse,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetHelpCommand
```

I am pretty new to the PowerShell environment, but I have run this command on my personal laptop just fine.  I get the errors above when running on my work desktop.

**Edit:**  Actually, I have found that running `get-help set-member` gives the same error as with the wildcard.

Comment: Try updating your help files with `Update-Help`.  Beyond that, `Set-Member` isn't a cmdlet I recognize.  At least, it doesn't exist on PSv4.0 on Win7 and doesn't appear to be in the PSCX that I can tell.

Comment: Do you have the same version of Powershell running in both environments? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Comment: @Bacon_Bits: You are correct about `set-member`. However, after running `update-help`, I still get the error with `get-help get-*`.

Comment: @steinar: I don't have the laptop on me, but I think it's running v3 or v4; whereas the desktop is running v5.